# How to fix "Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract' not found" after restoring backup of Magento installation?

Tags: php, error, fatal-error

After some issues in a webshop which I'm managing technically, I did a restore of a backup from the files. The backup was only one week old and worked well previously.

I removed all the files from the server and uploaded the backup. After that I get the following error:

"Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract' not found in /ROOTDIR/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Abstract.php on line 36"
For two days I tried several things like clearing the cache, reuploading (also older backups), checking file permissions, code fixes, but in any case, I still get this error.

The files and classes do exist physically, checked all logging and tracing, but nothing to get there.

Has anyone any suggestion where to look for the problem, or how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Magento version: 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the meantime. If anyone is bumping into this one, just make sure that the folder "product" in the path "/ROOTFOLDER/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block" starts with a capital "Product". By origin it's delivered with a lowercase.